# Tkinter - When I try to print a varibale that I used Entry to define, the print returns ".!entry"

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm learning Tkinter and I'm trying to set a global variable using `Entry`:

```
def initial_user_name_set():
    global user_name

    initial_greeting_label()

    user_name = Entry(root)
    user_name.pack()

    user_name_enter_button()
```

So that I can create a Label with a unique output depending on the `Entry` value (The `user_name_enter_button` function is just a button that calls the `time_based_greeting` function when pressed:

```
def time_based_greeting():
    user_name.get()

    if currentTime.hour < 12:
        morning_greeting_label()

    elif 12 <= currentTime.hour < 18:
        afternoon_greeting_label()

    else:
        evening_greeting_label()

    print(user_name)
```

An example of the greeting labels:

```
def evening_greeting_label():
    evening_greeting = Label(root, text="Good evening, " + user_name.get() + ".")
    evening_greeting.pack()
```

Now this alone works perfectly fine. If you were to input your name as `"Joe"`; then the label will be `"Good evening, Joe."`

However, when I later try to `print` the `user_name` variable; I simply get `".!entry"` printed into the terminal instead of `"Joe"`.

I am utterly confused as to why this is happening and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also please let me know if I could layout my question any better, thank you.

Comment: An entry _object_ is not the same as  the data _in_ the entry. You're printing the object, not the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite obvious, `user_name` is an `Entry` object. You are instantiating a class `Entry` in the name of a variable `user_name` so you can use various methods of it, like `user_name.get()` which returns what you type inside the entry widget. If you print `user_name` alone, you will get `'.!entry'` which is referring that `user_name` is an `Entry` object, maybe call it tkinters way of identifying objects of its classes. You can even try `print(evening_greeting)` and it will be something like `'.!labeln'` where `n` is the number of order of the widget and `.` is the main root window.

TL;DR: `user_name` is an `Entry` object and `user_name.get()` is a method of the object `user_name` that returns the value typed inside the entry widget.